# Last post was missing code so re-posting - newbie Java code. (Sams Java in 24 hours)

Tags: java, applet

I'm following the guide in the book mentioned above, though the code below won't work. It's giving me an error on lines 12 and 15. As far as I can tell, the code exactly matches that of the guide so can anybody see any glaring errors I've made? I am using netbeans. Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class HourFourThree extends javax.swing.JApplet {
    int number;

    public void init() {
        number = 225;
    }

   public void paint(Graphics screen) {
       Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
       screen2D.drawString("The square root of ") +
               number +
               " is " +
               Math.sqrt(number), 5, 50);
   } 
}
```

Comment: What are your line 12 and 15?

Comment: Remove the close paren after "square root of"

Comment: Probably a cut and paste error but this import line don't look right - enterimport java.awt.*;

Comment: Why was this question closed as 'too localised'? In what way does this question only serve a 'small geographic area, specific moment in time or extraordinarily narrow situation'? It seems like a genuine question for help regarding syntax and debugging in general, especially given it's a new programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Too many parens:

```
screen2D.drawString("The square root of ") +
```

change to:

```
screen2D.drawString("The square root of " +
```

Netbeans is probably already showing you unmatched paren.

Comment: Oh wow - I stared at that code for ages and just could not see a problem. Thanks so much :)

Comment: This is how you close this question - thank you Tomasz Nurkiewicz.